# MAE/MSE with or without square root

Tags: information-theory, recommender-system, information-retrieval

I read some papers about recommender systems and information retrieval, where Mean Absolut Error and Mean Squared Error are mentioned. But I've found some differences between the formal definition of this two formulars. At one paper the MAE and MSE are WITH a square root and in other papers (or only resources) without. Basically, I saw this versions:

$$
MAE_1 = \frac{1}{|TS|} \sum_{(u,i) \in TS} |\hat r_{ui} - r_{ui}|
$$
$$
MAE_2 = \sqrt{
 \frac{1}{|TS|} \sum_{(u,i) \in TS} |\hat r_{ui} - r_{ui}|
}
$$
$$
MSE_1 = \frac{1}{|TS|} \sum_{(u,i) \in TS} (\hat r_{ui} - r_{ui})^2
$$
$$
MSE_2 = \sqrt{
 \frac{1}{|TS|} \sum_{(u,i) \in TS} (\hat r_{ui} - r_{ui})^2
}
$$

I think that the MSE is without the square root, because otherwise the RMSE would be the same. But I'm not sure.

With the MAE I'm also not sure. Is the MAE **with** a square root, or is there something like Root Mean Absolute Error (RMAE) as RMSE is for MSE?

Hope someone can help me. thx!